# SQL Coding to Categorize Data and Find Days Since Last Reported

Tags: sql, filtering, average, cumulative-sum

UPDATE: This has been solved. I created a "calculated variable" in tableau called [Lab Volume] and put this code into the calculation:

```
If [Average Results Per Day] <= 25 THEN 'Low'
ELSEIF  [Average Results Per Day] > 25 and [Average Results Per Day] < 75 THEN 'Medium'
ELSEIF [Average Results Per Day] >= 75 THEN 'High' 
END
```

Thank you for your help!

ORIGINAL POST: I am having trouble figuring out how to create new categories of data, sum these categories, and then find how many days since the lab last reported.
Basically I have a list of unique [patientIDs], [Lab_Name], [result_reported_date], which I believe are the only variables I need for this project. SQL code will go into Tableau for data viz.

Here is my dilemma:

(1)  I need to average the number of reported lab results for each laboratory [lab_names] and then categorize them into three volume categories (low volume labs, medium volume labs, high volume labs) based upon how many samples submitted each day in the last 30-day window: low is <25 samples/day; medium is 25-50 samples/day; high is 75+ samples/day.

Input looks something like this, with mulitple labs over multiple days with a sum of the number of samples submitted. The file has 750 different labs, with dates going back 30+ days, and a sum of the samples submitted on each day.

| Lab_Name | Date | Samples_Submitted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LabA | 1/01/22 | 80 |
| LabB | 1/01/22 | 22 |
| LabA | 1/02/22 | 101 |
| LabB | 1/01/22 | 12 |
| LabA | 1/03/22 | 95 |
| LabB | 1/03/22 | 80 |

Output would be something like this:

| Lab_Name | Vol_category | Average_sample_per30day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LabA | low | 22 |
| LabB | medium | 35 |
| LabC | high | 85 |
| LabD | low | 15 |
| LabE | medium | 32 |

This is the code I have to count the number of samples submitted by Lab_Name. I don't know how to average the number of samples submitted over the last 30-days and then create low, medium, high categories.

```
select 
Lab_Name,
count(Lab_Name) as Lab_count
from dbo.Lab_tests

where 
result_reported_date > '2022-07-01' and
Test_LOINC in ('41458-1', '94306-8', '94309-2', '94500-6', '94502-2', '94531-1', '94533-7', 
                '94534-5', '94559-2', '94565-9', '94568-9', '94640-0', '94756-4', '94757-2', 
                '94759-8', '94760-6', '94845-5', '95406-5', '95409-9', '95423-0', '95425-5', 
                '95608-6', '96094-8', '96123-5', '96448-6', '96986-5', '99999-9', '94558-4', 
                                '95209-3', '96119-3', '97097-0') 
group by Lab_Name 
order by Lab_count desc ;
```

Comment: @JonasMetzler thank you for the feedback. Does this make it more understandable?

Comment: Could you please add the corresponding sample input for that outcome? You are talking about an average, but your query doesn't build one. That's confusing.

Comment: I don't understand what you are averaging.  Your code is generating one count per lab.  Did you want to generate a count per lab per some time period instead?  Then you could get an average of those counts for each lab.

Comment: I have a raw file with hundreds of labs and how many samples they each have submitted each day. From this, I need to determine the average number of samples submitted by each lab per week, over the last 30-days. Once I have that number, I can divide them into low, medium, and high categories.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I will add a corresponding in table.

Comment: This needs to be an automated process in Tableau. I am trying to make SQL code to import into Tableau to make three tables -- (1) Low Volume labs that report < 25 samples per week on average over the last 30-days; (2) Medium Volume labs that report >= 25 to < 75 samples per week on average over the last 30-days; and (3) High Volume Labs that report >= 75 samples per week on average over the last 30-days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe...

```
select 
Lab_Name,
count(Lab_Name) as Lab_count,

CASE 
WHEN count(Lab_Name) <= 25 THEN 'Low'
WHEN count(Lab_Name) > 25 and count(Lab_Name) <= 50 THEN 'Medium'
WHEN count(Lab_Name) >= 75 THEN 'High'
ELSE 'Medium_High'
END AS Vol_category

from dbo.Lab_tests
```

Comment: Ari, that was a BIG help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the code below to create a variable in Tableau "Lab_Volume" utilizing a version of the the code provided above, after calculating the average test over the last 30 days [test/30 days]:

```
If [Test/30 days] <= 25 THEN 'Low'
ELSEIF  [Test/30 days] > 25 and [Test/30 days] < 75 THEN 'Medium'
ELSEIF [Test/30 days] >= 75 THEN 'High' 
END
```